# Cypress issue with building with Typescript in the plugins file. Have to close & restart every time there is an error

Tags: typescript, cypress

So, I am needing to dispatch in my Cypress tests to pre-saturate my redux. It works but whenever I generate an error, or a test fails, I get this cryptic message:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/bill/Library/Application Support/Cypress/cy/production/projects/coresite-69f7195282475693846caddd826bc773/bundles/cypress/support/index.js'
```

> This occurred while Cypress was compiling and bundling your test code.
> This is usually caused by:
>
> A missing file or dependency A syntax error in the file or one of its
> dependencies

Then I have to close my cypress tests, then restart with "npx cypress open". Then its fine.

I think it has to do with my addition of this in the /plugins/index.js file

```
const wp = require("@cypress/webpack-preprocessor");

module.exports = (on) => {
    const options = {
      webpackOptions: require('../../webpack.config')({ env: 'development' }),
    };
    on('file:preprocessor', wp(options));
};
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? I had to add that plugin cause in one of my files I'm doing:

```
cy.on("emit:reduxStore", async (store) => {
    store.dispatch(actions.updateAreas(data));
});
```

Comment: Did you manage to fix this issue? I'm having the exact same issue at the moment

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. The issue was caused by using the `CleanWebpackPlugin`. I removed it from the plugins array, and the error was gone. It seems the preprocessor and the plugin conflict with each other.